# asp.net webform printing consistency

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css, webforms

I have a webform that my users need to print, but I'm running into issues when they have different print zooms or other printing options.

I do have a print stylesheet, which works great on another webform, but this form has problems like elements vanishing off-page, unwanted whitespace, etc.

Is there any way (using CSS, asp.net or JavaScript) to standardize the way this form looks when printed on different computers/browsers?

NOTE: I'm fairly certain I could dynamically create a PDF using code or some reporting service, but then I would need to maintain the display in 2 places.  Is there a solution where I only need to maintain the design in 1 place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use something like [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) which will give you a consistent print for every user, and it takes your page as it currently stands.

Comment: I love the idea, but I'm not sure how to integrate this with my page?

Comment: Your suggestion lead me to Pechkin, a C# verson of wkhtmltopdf https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin which I'm experimenting with now.